# Why were all three of my toilet bowls empty upon returning home?

Tags: plumbing

Away for a week, came home to find all 3 toilet bowls dry - 2 on upper floor and 1 on lower.  Each flushed and filled fine, except with a kind of clunk sound with each flush.  No sign of leak anywhere in 10 year old house.  We heading away again; feeling a little nervous.  Any suggestions? 
Connected to community sewer, no dog left home alone for a week yikes!  Very hot & dry in Kelowna , maybe Jack is correct.  Will try the plastic wrap nex week.  Thanks all

Comment: Welcome. You'd want to revise to tell us a little something about your plumbing. Community sewer? Septic system? Pipe to the river? PVC? Cast iron? Stone troughs? (Help us help you.)

Comment: Do you have a dog?

Comment: If this never happens when you're home, at least you can rule out siphoning or a blocked vent stack.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me a few times when I'd be gone and the house would be vacant for a week. The water just evaporated. The tanks were full but the bowls in both bathrooms were dry. I solved the problem by covering the bowls with Glad Wrap. Worked like a charm. Just make sure to remember to remove it when you get back... Good luck.

Comment: Remember to remove it :) plus 1.... Can you imagine SWMBO and a mercy rush... perhaps a big note and writing on the gladwrap aka clingfilm...

Comment: Gave me a good laugh even before coffee. Where are you at mike??

Comment: wouldn't a single flush solve this problem?

Comment: @sickest It  would if someone was there to do it.  Bowls dried up, the traps would be next.